# Is Everett Ross related to Thunderbolt Ross?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america, marvel, captain-america-civil-war

In Captain America : Civil War, is Martin Freeman's character Everett Ross,
related to Thunderbolt Ross?

Comment: They aren't related in the comics and I've seen nothing to indicate that they're related in the films

Comment: The film averts the [One Steve Limit](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OneSteveLimit).

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive, or at least as comprehensive as you can be when trying to prove a negative. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 8):

In the comics, there's never been a suggestion that Everett Ross is related to Thunderbolt Ross or Betty Ross.

According to a blogpost on [his creator's website](http://digitalpriest.com/legacy/comics/adventures/frames/panther_intro.htm), when he was initially written, the writers bandied around a variety of names before settling on *'Everett K. Ross'* as an homage to the character [Alex P. Keaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alex_P._Keaton):

> The guys loved the idea, and we started hammering away at the details.
>   **The character's name was, literally, Chandler for the first couple of
>   weeks, until I settled on a Alex P. Keaton vibe in Everett K. Ross.**
>   Most fans assumed him to be a one-off of Michael J. Fox, and Fox could
>   certainly bring him to life, but I was writing Chandler, not Alex. I
>   had Ross appear in KA-ZAR #17 as a warm-up of sorts, a run-through
>   with the quick-witted, sardonic half-pint, who effortlessly got Ka-Zar
>   off of an attempted murder charge.

Within the **MCU**, there's also no indication that they're related. In the canon prose novel [*Avengers: Infinity War - The Heroes Journey*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War:_The_Heroes%27_Journey), Everett Ross refers to "the other Ross" without offering any indication that they share a personal connection.

> "They're all in custody. Ross has them. You know, *the other Ross*". He meant General Thaddeus Ross, who had spearheaded the effort to rein in the Avengers.